# Browser show html code for a razor object

Tags: html, layout, razor

I have this follow code, and into the item.TrunkedDescription exists this value:

> `<p> Este &eacute; o congresso!</p>`

```
<span class="description">
      @item.TrunkedDescription
</span>
```

My browser is showing the value `<p> Este &eacute; o congresso!</p>`, but the correct is "Este é o congresso".

Any help?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the problem is?  Are the `<p>` and `</p>` tags inappropriate, or is it the `!` that doesn't belong?

Comment: I solve this problem with @Html.Raw(item.TrunkedDescription). ! belong to string